# Are event arguments passed by reference or value in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, events, event-handling, reference-type

A rather simple question (I think), but I don't seem to see an answer already.  I know that some values are passed via value (like int and long), and others are passed by reference (like Strings) when you pass them to functions.

In my program, I have it using background worker so that the GUI doesn't lock up when we are doing a long process in the background.  I need to pass data back to the UI thread from another file, so I have been using events for that.  Now I need to send a list of arrays of Strings back to the GUI thread to handle there, and I am worried how it will be handled.  Basically, in the worker thread, I have a loop that will fill up the list, send it back to the GUI via an event handler, and then clear it so it can fill it up on the next pass through the loop and start again.

I am worried that when I do this, if the list is passed by reference, then on the UI thread, I would think that it would be cleared mid-read since the worker thread will still be clearing it in the background.  Passing by would be far preferable in this case, and I can find ways to force it(copy to some holder array or add a mutex or something of the sort), but I thought it would be good to know if event arguments are passed via reference or value in general, or is it just the same as methods, and it will pass them as arguments are normally passed?

Comment: What you know is incorrect. Strings and are passed by value as well. In fact everything is passed by value in C# unless you explicitly pass by reference.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventargs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx look at the link for MSDN explanation

Comment: I think I was mixing it up with arrays that are assigned by reference (ie (temparray = array1) just makes temparray point to array1, but to make a new one I need (temparray = array1.clone()), or something of the like)

Comment: @Xantham: Arrays are reference types. So the value of `array1` is just a reference. All assignment just copies the value of one expression to a variable (or property).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> I know that some values are passed via value (like int and long), and others are passed by reference (like Strings) when you pass them to functions.

Nope. By default everything is passed by value - but when you're using reference types, the "everything" is a reference. That reference is passed by value. That's *not* the same as pass by reference. See [my article on parameter passing](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html) for more details.

Event arguments are exactly the same - any references are passed by value, assuming the corresponding delegate doesn't use `out` or `ref` parameters.

EDIT: So to address your concern: yes, if your event argument is mutable and you're going to act on a different thread, you should create a copy first... or alternatively, pass the existing reference and then create a new (empty) list in your worker thread.

Comment: It would appear a lot of us have been grossly mis-informed terminology wise. =)

Comment: You learn something new every day! I previously thought that passing an object parameter by ref was redundant. Thanks for informing us!

Comment: So, just to be sure about the "reference is passed by value" and "pass by reference".  Would I be correct in saying taht "ref passed by value" means that if the address of whatever the reference was looking at was 0x1337, I would pass back 0x1337 (the address by value).   And so that the "pass by reference" would be that I would have something that always points to whatever the reference was referencing, whether it is at address 0x1337 or somewhere else?

Comment: @Xantham: I don't think it's helpful to talk about addresses, to be honest. It's better to show *actual code* and ask about the effects. (But read my article first, and hopefully it will sort things out.)

Answer (score 4):

Arguments themselves are passed by value by default. However, depending on their type, they can be values or references to the actual values you're working with.

Note that this is not the same as what is commonly known as *passing by reference*, as the very value actually passed to an argument is copied (i.e. *passed by value*). However, the effect is similar in that if you change the referenced object within the method, the changes will be visible outside of the method (in the code where you invoked the method), too.

Now, when passing by value, there is nothing special about event arguments; whether the values are copied or only their references entirely depends on their type. So, as you said, `int` and `long` arguments (and some more, any `struct` types) are value types, while others like `string` (and any class instances) are reference types.

Note that a true *passing by reference* is possible in C#, too, but that requires the [`ref` keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

In the standard event pattern there are two references passed in:

```
 void FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) { ... }
```

those two references are passed 'by value', using for example `sender = null` will have no effect outside the handling method.

But you can easily pass a value back:

```
void FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    ...
    e.Cancel = true;  // this will pass back to the caller
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The event arguments are passed according to ***the type of the arguments*** and ***the signature of the event handler's delegate*** (*in*, out or ref) - if it is a class, then a copy of the reference is passed, if it is a struct, then the copy of the value is passed (assuming signature does not specify out or ref).

The event arguments are usually a class (usually inherits from [EventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventargs.aspx)) and are often used to return values such as eventArgs.DoCancel to the caller.

Comment: Please see my answer - reference type values are *not* passed by reference by default. The reference is passed by value, which is different.

Comment: Because it is wrong.  Reference types are passed by copy of reference by default.  It is a difference that matters and few seem to understand it.

Comment: The reference is passed, not the value, I didn't mean that the actual reference can be changed as in ref or out.

Comment: And I quote - *"if it is a class, then by reference"*.  No, it is passed by copy of reference.

Comment: The reference to the object is passed, however, not the reference to reference.

Comment: ...A *copy* of the reference is passed.  It is an important difference.

Comment: Copy of reference - not of the value - isn't that what the OP asked?

Comment: @DannyVarod: A copy of the reference is passed *by value*. That is not the meaning of *pass by reference*. It's an important distinction to make, and both you and the OP have failed to make it.

Comment: The right answer is "by default, *everything* is passed by value.  In the case of a reference type, the reference is what is passed by value"

Comment: @JonSkeet I thought that was clear from my answer, however, if it is not I will edit.

Comment: @DannyVarod: Basically while your answer uses the term "by reference" for the default behaviour, it'll probably be wrong :)

Comment: @DannyVarod: Better, but still not quite right. The nature of the passing depends on the parameter modifier - `out` or `ref` or nothing. That's *all* that affects "by value" or "by reference".