# Attach an event handler to an event stored in a list

Tags: c#, delegates

I want to make a list that stores some events and attach event handler to the event through the list.

So I make a `List<dele>`  add the event `anEvent` into it, then I try to attach an event handler to that event, but at last `anEvent` still got no event handler attached to it, the program outputs True. But the delegate stored at `list[0]` did get the lambda expression.

```
 public delegate void dele();

class Program
{
   static event dele anEvent;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<dele> list=new List<dele>();
        list.Add(anEvent);
        list[0]+=()=>{Console.WriteLine("BEEP!");};
        Console.WriteLine(anEvent==null);
    }
}
```

Isn't delegate a reference type? It seems that `eventhandler` and `list[0]` refers to different objects. I wonder why.

If I want that `anEvent` gets the event handler when I attach the handler to `list[0]`, what should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: _the program outputs `True`_ Sure???

Comment: The output is False i tested it

Comment: Delegates are value types.

Comment: Your program outputs false.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3854421/7974050        and         https://stackoverflow.com/a/11800608/7974050

Comment: _what should I do?_ Delete the question, which is based on a false assumption!

Comment: I‘m sorry. I copied the wrong code. I removed the statement anEvent=list[0];. It shouldn't be there. I was just testing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A delegate is basically a contract for a method implementation.
Kinda like an interface is a contract for class implementations.

The CLI (Common Language Infrastructure) specification says that [delegates are reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/delegate).

> A delegate is a reference type that can be used to encapsulate a named
>   or an anonymous method. Delegates are similar to function pointers in
>   C++; however, delegates are type-safe and secure. For applications of
>   delegates, see Delegates and Generic Delegates.

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905962/why-are-delegates-reference-types) question and also have a look at [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7906788/4992212) one.

I have converted the method into a non anonymous method for debugging reasons

```
 public delegate void dele();
 public static event dele anEvent;

  static void Main(string[] args) {
      List<dele> list = new List<dele>();
      list.Add(anEvent);
      list[0] += Dele;
      list[0].Invoke(); //this actually gets invoked and does not throw!
      anEvent = list[0];
      Console.WriteLine(anEvent == null); //the output is false
      anEvent.Invoke(); // this also gets s invoked and does not throw
  }

private static void Dele() { //this gets invoked 2 times as expected
  Console.WriteLine("Beep"); // this gets printed after invoking the event
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry for that. The statement anEvent=list[0]; shouldn't has been there. I removed it.  Then the output will be Beep and true. That means anEvent didn't get Dele and list[0] got, do I think it right? But why? Delegate is reference type then why did list[0] and anEvent get different value?

Comment: I think I got it. So when I pass `anEvent` to the `List.Add` method, it actually copies the delegate in the event, then I attach an event handler to the delegate stored in `list[0]`,because delegate is an immutable type so it doesn't affect the delegate in `anEvent`, for this reason it won't work. Is that right?